# Pause HTML5 audio whilst element still visible from AJAX return

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html5-audio

I have a HTML page that polls a PHP script connected to a DB to see if any new items were received (new items are marked **NEW**) if there is, then an element `#audio` is sent to the browser so a sound can be played:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
if ($('#audio').length) {
$('#sound').get(0).play();
}
```

});

The `#sound` is in the page's HTML so if #audio is returned with the items marked as NEW then the sound is played.

The polling returns all items within a certain time frame so **OLD and NEW** items can be returned which is why if there is one marked NEW I attach an `#audio` to make a sound.

Once the sound is played the user presses a button to update the NEW status to OLD in the DB using update.php and at the same time pause the sound.

```
$('body').on('click','.acc',function() {
    $('#sound').get(0).pause();
    var itemID = $(this).data("id");
{
        $.post("update.php",
{
    id: itemID
},);
    }
});
```

Now the problem I am having is that although this works, sometimes the delay in updating in the server (from NEW to OLD) causes the sound to play because the `#audio` still exists.

I have tried to hide the element on click as well but that still has the same effect i.e. `#audio` is still returned whilst the updating is in process.

What do I need to do, can I use a different technique to stop the sound whilst the server is still processing?

Hope this makes sense if not let me know and I'll explain further and thanks in advance.